# Markdown for literal '@'

Tags: support, markdown

How does one write...

```
@name and @other
```

...in the comment feed, where the @ characters are meant as literals, not as markdown?

Comment: I can't event enter this comment (without the space after the ampersand): @ name and @ other   -- This results in an error.

Comment: Testing Aaron's answer: `@name and `@other

Comment: Backtick works! Thanks Aaron! But why do the two ampersands render differently? The font for `@name is a lot different to the font for `@other ?

Comment: That didn't happen in my example below. I suspect you only correctly back-ticked one of them. You can enter up to one `@word` without using markdown. However a user named `@other` might get notified. :-)

Comment: Oh - may be the backtick goes **BOTH** before and after. Testing: `@`name and `@`other .

Comment: If you just surround the `@` it injects some white space. If you want to surround the entire `@name` so that it is one word (and it will be in a different font), do it like I showed in my answer.

Comment: Can you post exaclty what I should type in a code-sectioned answer box please?

Comment: I thought I did that? Which part have I not demonstrated? I typed the text you should enter in a code block, and even copied and pasted that into a comment on my answer to demonstrate. Could you try copying the text in the code block in my answer and pasting it into a comment? Otherwise I am not sure where the disconnect is...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to use code with a backtick:

```
Write your comment with `@name` and `@other` like this
```

I don't know of a way to enter more than one word beginning with `@name` without using markdown and without generating an error about notifying multiple people.

Comment: Demonstration: Write your comment with `@name` and `@other` like this

Comment: Testing: `@name` and `@answer`.